# ASP.NET getting indexed values when deserializing JSON into a dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, dynamic

So I have a JSON string that I am passing from an AJAX call to my controller. I have a list of indexed values that I am passing into a dynamic object.

I deserialize the JSON with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(s)
```

This is the output from that dynamic object:

```
"RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId": "269",
 "RolePermissions[0].HasAccess": "false",
 "RolePermissions[1].RolePermissionId": "270",
 "RolePermissions[1].HasAccess": "false",
 "RolePermissions[2].RolePermissionId": "271",
 "RolePermissions[2].HasAccess": "true",
 "RolePermissions[3].RolePermissionId": "272",
 "RolePermissions[3].HasAccess": "false"
```

When I try to access the a property of the object with

```
ssObj.RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId
```

I get a RuntimeBinderException. I have tried to use JObject.Parse, which works great, but for some reason, the values in the array become out of order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please share the value of `s` that you are trying to deserialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to do `RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId` you are trying to access a nested collection containing an object with a property `RolePermissionId` at index 0.  But your JSON doesn't represent a hierarchy of objects, it represents a single flat object with key/value pairs whose keys contain periods and brackets.  Since c# identifiers don't allow such characters so you have no way to access such property values using `dynamic` directly.

Instead, your options include:

1. Take advantage of the fact that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(s)` actually returns a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and use its [dictionary indexer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm):

   ```
   var ssObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(s);
   var rolePermissionId = (string)ssObj["RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId"];
   ```
2. If you prefer a slightly more typed solution, you could deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`:

   ```
   var ssDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(s);
   var rolePermissionId = (string)ssDict["RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId"];
   ```
3. Or for a much more statically typed solution, parse explicitly to a `JObject` and use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm):

   ```
   var jObj = JObject.Parse(s);
   var rolePermissionId = (string)jObj["RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId"];
   ```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/96zTxI) showing the various options.

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple and easy solution that is easy to loop through. All options are great and highly appreciate it! I can't upvote because I don't have a high enough reputation, but I marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the data being sent via AJAX then make sure the data sent is properly formatted.

In order to be able to deserialize variable `s` like:

```cs
var ssObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(s);
```

and access the resulting object in this manner:

```cs
ssObj.RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId
```

then the JSON value in `s`, based on your sample and desired behavior, would have to look like this:

```json
{
    "RolePermissions": [
        {
            "RolePermissionId": "269",
            "HasAccess": "false"
        },
        {
            "RolePermissionId": "270",
            "HasAccess": "false"
        },
        {
            "RolePermissionId": "271",
            "HasAccess": "true"
        },
        {
            "RolePermissionId": "272",
            "HasAccess": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```

This quick unit test showed that it is possible to get indexed values when deserializing JSON into a dynamic object

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetIndexedValuesWhenDeserializingJSONIntoDynamicObject() {

        var s = @"
        {
            'RolePermissions': [
                {
                    'RolePermissionId': '269',
                    'HasAccess': 'false'
                },
                {
                    'RolePermissionId': '270',
                    'HasAccess': 'false'
                },
                {
                    'RolePermissionId': '271',
                    'HasAccess': 'true'
                },
                {
                    'RolePermissionId': '272',
                    'HasAccess': 'false'
                }
            ]
        }
        ";

        var ssObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(s);

        var result = ssObj.RolePermissions[0].RolePermissionId;

        Assert.AreEqual("269", (string)result);
    }
}
```

So you need to make sure you are sending well formatted JSON to your controller to achieve desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer @dbc gave was more what I was looking for, but I appreciate the answer!